# RISK style game in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am basically creating a 2D RISK style game using LibGDX, however, I don't know of any good ways to implement borders between the world territories. For example say the user clicks within the bounds of a territory, how would the I determine which territory the user clicked on?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make each country an Actor subclass and add it to a stage.  Then, register each country Actor with an EventListener subclass that can interpret inputs.  Google scene2d to get some other ideas.

Comment: For those that marked my question as off-topic, I wasn't seeking debugging help, I was seeking methods of implementation, not everything in a program revolves around a few lines of code.

Comment: @Austin I tried your method and it works, but I ran into some problems. Would you mind taking a look at my code to see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about implementing a RISK game myself a few years ago, but I never did. However here is my idea on how to detect which country a user selects: (Warning, it might be a bad idea).

Have a second map (only in memory) where all the countries are color coded. When the user clicks, look up the color of the pixel with the click coordinates on the color-map and then look up the color code in a `Map<Color, Country>`

I'm not sure how good that idea is, an alternative would be to define the country borders as polygons and then do Point-in-Polygon tests on each country.

Comment: Hmm seems like a good idea. I didn't want to end up making polygons for the territories :).  I'll give it a shot!